# Rails app and mongdb database code Explain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to mogodb and forked one rails app which use Mongoid - 3.00 as mapper. Now one of my model is this :

```
class Portfolio
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

  """
  Folder format:
  {
   name: <folder name>,
   stocks: [
    {
       name: <stock name>,
      id: <stock id>,
      qty: <stock quantity>
     }
    ]
  }
  """
  field :folders, type: Array
  end
```

I am running rails app like this : 1) bundle and 2) rails s

I have some doubts 
1)Right now model are independent , Suppose if I can see the database in the mongodb shell how i can see different fields declared in the database?

2)In the above code what is the function of code between """ and """.?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the code between `"""` but you simply do this to add attributes to your model using mongoid:

```
class Portfolio
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :a_string, type: String, default: ''
 field :an_integer, type: Integer, default: 0
 field :a_hash, type: Hash, default: {}
end
```

From mongodb shell:

```
> mongo
> use your_database_name
> db.portfolios.findOne()
```

More information on mongoid [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html)

More information on mongodb [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/)

Comment: Can you tell me in ruby what does code between triplet quote stands for?

Comment: Also show collections is showing class name , How can i check different Attribute / field of the class from the mongo shell?

Comment: `findOne()` will show your the attributes and its values. Don't know about the triple quotes.

Comment: I first did show collections which gives Stock_prices null , may be there is no document entered. What is the command to enter document using shell.

Comment: What about looking around through the documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/ ;)